# How can I remove arrows from my slideshow when the list hits the end or beginning

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, slideshow, carousel

I have a slideshow on my page. There are five items. I have two arrows that cycle through these items. When the page loads I hide the left arrow using css and when the slideshow reaches the end I want to hide the right arrow. I've tried to do tricks like detecting the parents "margin-left: 0" to remove the left arrow from the page but so far I haven't had any success. I also haven't been able to remove the right arrow at all. Below is my code. I know there are simpler ways to do this but I'm inexperienced with this sort of problem.

```
<div id="tips-navbar">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li id="the-best-mashed-potatoes" class="selected">
        <div class="st-label">The Best Mashed Potatoes</div>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="fully-loaded-mashed-potatoes">
        <div class="st-label">Fully Loaded Mashed Potatoes</div>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="perfect-mashed-sweet-potatoes">
        <div class="st-label">Perfect Mashed Sweet Potatoes</div>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="how-to-make-mash-tinis">
        <div class="st-label">How to Make Mash-tinis</div>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="simple-smashed-potatoes">
        <div class="st-label">Simple Smashed Potatoes</div>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </li>            
    </ul>
        <a class="st-brownBg st-left-m">
            <div class="st-arrowVideoBack"></div>
        </a>

        <a class="st-brownBg  st-right-m">
            <div class="st-arrowVideoNext"></div>
        </a>
  </div>

    $(function vNext(){
        $( ".st-right-m" ).click(function() {
            $( "#tips-navbar ul" ).animate({
                marginLeft: "-=431"
            }, 500);
            $( ".st-left-m" ).css('display','block');
            if($('.st-right-m'.click() >= 4)){
                $('.st-right-m').hide()
            }
        });
    });

    $(function vPrev(){
        $( ".st-left-m" ).click(function() {
            $( "#tips-navbar ul" ).animate({
                marginLeft: "+=431"
            }, 500);
            if($($this).parents('.slides').css('marginLeft' === 0 + 'px')){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

    });
```

sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/oq46u3wf/1/

Comment: Consider updating your HTML first, because it is invalid at this moment. You can not put `a` tags directly inside a `ul` without a `li`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code several times and forgot to put that back.

Comment: I'm not seeing code related to the Bootstrap slider/carousel....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following with your JS code:

```
$.current = 1;

$.updateArrows = function () {
    if ($.current <= 1) {
        if ($( ".st-left-m" ).is(':visible')) {
            $( ".st-left-m" ).hide();
        }
    } else {
        $( ".st-left-m" ).show();
    }
    if ($.current >= 5) {
        if ($( ".st-right-m" ).is(':visible')) {
            $( ".st-right-m" ).hide();
        }
    } else {
        $( ".st-right-m" ).show();
    }
};

$(function vNext(){
    $( ".st-right-m" ).click(function() {
        $( "#tips-navbar ul" ).animate({
            marginLeft: "-=431"
        }, 500);
        $.current++;
        $.updateArrows();
    });
});

$(function vPrev(){
    $( ".st-left-m" ).click(function() {
        $( "#tips-navbar ul" ).animate({
            marginLeft: "+=431"
        }, 500);
        $.current--;
        $.updateArrows();
    });
});
```

What we actually do here is:

1. Keep a var with the current slide, which updates with every click.
2. Also with every click we update the arrows (with an extra function) which checks the current slide, if it is 1 it hides the left arrow, if 5 it hides the right arrow.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery to find the "last-child", in your case the last < li >, then act upon that. See this reference: http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

//For your example

```
$(".slides li").is(':last-child')
```

Comment: How would you do that? How would you 'detect' that you are at the last child?

Comment: I added the code to my answer as to how to detect that you're at the last child. @putvande

Comment: And how would you put that in OPs function? OP is animating the parent `ul`. I don't see how this `last-child` selector will work.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but by detecting you are at the last child, you could then hide/remove the arrow via jQuery. I don't see why this has to be included in the function at all, but it could with a simple if test, no?

Comment: Problem is when I click the '<a>' no class of "active" is added to the list so simply calling ":last-child" won't do anything.

Comment: How much more of my code do you need? This is the basic concept.

Comment: A working JSFiddle would be nice. There seems like there are much better ways of creating a slideshow, than this approach.